# Keep page refresh Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am struggling to keep the session open all the time. The code executes, but only when the link is present.

```
driver.refresh
```

doesn't seem to keep the page refreshed.

Is there a way to refresh the page every couple seconds?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

user_name = "username"
password = "password"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://mywebsite.com/boardslots.aspx?date=07%2F31%2F2022')
element = driver.find_element(By.ID,"txtUsername")
element.send_keys(user_name)
element = driver.find_element(By.ID,"txtPassword")
element.send_keys(password)
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

while True:
try:
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Claim")
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.refresh
else:
   driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Claim").click()

try:
#    element = WebDriverWait(driver,1)
element= WebDriverWait(driver,    
10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html   
/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]/a')))

finally:

    driver.find_element(BY.ID,"btnSubmitSingle").click()


#/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]/a
```

Comment: Doesn't `driver.refresh` on the same page defeats the purpose of automation?

Comment: I don't know. I got it from one of the answers here.